# Serving files with IdHTTPServer when the files are being written

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, indy10, c++builder-xe5

I'm working with a `TIdHTTPServer` to serve files to clients, using the `ResponseInfo->ServeFile` function. This works fine for files that are "static": not being written by some other process. As far as I can see from the code, the ServeFile function internally uses a `TIdReadFileExclusiveStream`, which disallows me from reading a file being written, but I need to be able to send also files that are being written by some other process.

So, I moved to create a FileStream myself and use the `ContentStream` property to return it to the client, but I get a 0 bytes file in the client (for any file, being written or not), and I can't see what I'm missing or doing wrong. Here is the code I'm using on the `OnCommandGet` event handler:

```
AResponseInfo->ContentStream = new TFileStream(path, fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyNone);
AResponseInfo->ContentStream->Position = 0;
AResponseInfo->ContentLength = AResponseInfo->ContentStream->Size;
AResponseInfo->ResponseNo = 200;
AResponseInfo->WriteHeader();
AResponseInfo->WriteContent();
```

The ContentLength property at this point has a valid value (i.e., the file size when calling ContentStream->Size), and that's what I would like to send to the client, even if the file changes in between.

I have tried removing the WriteContent() function, the WriteHeader(), but the results are the same. I searched for some examples but the few I found are more or less the same than this code, so I don't know what's wrong. Most examples don't include the WriteContent() call, that's why I have tried removing them, but there doesn't seem to be any difference.

As a side note: the files being written take 24 hours to finish writing, but that's to be expected from the client side: I just need the bytes already written at the time of the request (even somewhat less is valid). The files will never get deleted: they will just keep getting bigger.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Using Fiddler, I get some warnings on protocol violations, that would be related to this. I get, for instance:

`Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 111,628,288 bytes, but server sent 41 bytes`

The content length is correct, it's the file size, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong that makes the app sent just 41 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final working code is:

```
    std::unique_ptr< TFileStream >fs(new TFileStream(path, fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyNone));

    fs->Position = 0;
    __int64 size = fs->Size;

    AResponseInfo->ContentLength = size;
    AResponseInfo->ResponseNo    = 200;

    AResponseInfo->WriteHeader();

    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(fs.get(), size);
```

This allows the client to receive up to `size` bytes of the original file, even if the file is being written to at the same time.

For some reason passing the ContentStream did not return any content to the client, but doing the `IOHandler->Write` directly (which is what the ServeFile ends doing internally) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`WriteHeader()` and `WriteContent()` expect the `ContentStream` to be complete and unchanging at the time they are called.  `WriteHeader()` creates a `Content-Length` header using the current `ContentStream->Size` value if the `AResponseInfo->ContentLength` property is -1 (you are actually setting the value yourself), and `WriteContent()` sends only as many bytes as the current `ContentStream->Size` value says.  So your client is receiving 0 bytes because the file `Size` is still 0 at the time you are calling `WriteHeader()` and `WriteContent()`.

Neither `ServeFile()` nor `ContentStream` are suitable for your needs.  Since the file is being written live, you do not know the final file size when the HTTP headers are created and sent to the client.  So you **must** use HTTP 1.1's [`chunked` transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) to send the file data.  That will allow you to send the file data in chunks as the file is being written, and then signal the client when the file is finished.

However, `TIdHTTPServer` does not natively support sending `chunked` responses, so you will have to implement it manually, eg:

```cpp
TFileStream *fs = new TFileStream(path, fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyNone);
try
{
    AResponseInfo->ResponseNo = 200;
    AResponseInfo->TransferEncoding = "chunked";
    AResponseInfo->WriteHeader();

    TIdBytes buffer;
    buffer.Length = 1024;

    do
    {
        int NumRead = fs->Read(&buffer[0], 1024);
        if (NumRead == -1) RaiseLastOSError();
        if (NumRead == 0)
        {
            // check for EOF, unless you have another way to detect it...
            Sleep(1000);
            NumRead = fs->Read(&buffer[0], 1024);
            if (NumRead <= 0) break;
        }

        // send the current chunk
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(IntToHex(NumRead));
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(buffer, NumRead);
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn();
    }
    while (true);

    // send the last chunk to signal EOF
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn("0");

    // send any trailer headers you need, if any...

    // finish the transfer encoding
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn();
}
__finally
{
    delete fs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but: the Size I'm setting is not 0. It is the correct value in that moment for the requested file, say, 100mb, and I don't care if the file grows up (they never get smaller nor deleted) in between. I don't have a problem with sending less than the actual size. And the code I posted doesn't work either for already finished files. The client can't wait for the whole file as they take 24 hours to be written.

Comment: You don't need to set `AResponseInfo->ContentLength` manually if you are using `AResponseInfo->ContentStream` or `AResponseInfo->ServeFile()`, they handle the `ContentLength` for you.  But they do work, so if you are having problems with bad/missing data then you are probably doing something wrong in code you did not show in this question.

Comment: I guarantee you that when used properly, if the file is at least 111628288 bytes in size then at least 111628288 bytes will be sent. The only way it could send 41 bytes is if the file actually shrank to 41 bytes. However, there is a race condition between `WriteHeader()` and `WriteContent()`, so if the file GROWS, it is possible that `WriteContent()` may send MORE bytes than indicated in the `Content-Length` header generated by `WriteHeader()`, and that would be bad for the client.  That looks like a bug in `TIdHTTPServer` that needs to be fixed.

Comment: ... so you likely need to bypass `WriteContent()` and send the file data manually so it matches the actual `Content-Length` header that is sent.  Or at least wrap the source `TFileStream` in a custom `TStream` that ensures a consistent `Size` value even if the file grows while the stream is being used.

Comment: In general, `TIdHTTPServer` is not really designed to handle live data, so you may have to jump through some extra hoops to make it work.

Comment: I have tried with static files and I get the same behavior. As you say, there must be something I'm doing wrong, but there is no more code here to show (except the part before, where I localize the file to be sent). The 41 bytes are: `<HTML><BODY><B>200 OK</B></BODY></HTML>`. I have partly solved this in an ugly way: I copy the file to a temporary location and use ServeFile, but I would really like to avoid doing this.

Comment: That HTML is sent by `WriteContent()` when both `ContentText` is blank and `ContentStream` is nil.  `TIdHTTPServer` calls `WriteContent()` automatically when the `OnCommand...` event handler exits if `ContentText` or `ContentStream` are assigned.  In the code I gave you, that is not the case.  So `WriteContent()` would only be getting called if you are calling it yourself even if you are not assigning `ContentText` or `ContentStream`.

Comment: I changed the `WriteContent()` call for the same code that the ServeFile function does internally: call 'IOHandler.Write' with the TFileStream pointer and the size passed to the ContentLength, and now it works as expected. Does this makes any sense?

Comment: It does make sense, because neither `ContentText` nor `ContentStream` are being assigned when using `ServeFile()` (or code you copied from `ServeFile()`), and you removed your manual call to `WriteContent()` and `TIdHTTPServer` will not call `WriteContent()` automatically under these conditions, so the default HTML does not get sent.

Comment: Ok. The final code is exactly as I originally posted, but instead of `WriteContent` I'm calling `IOHandler->Write` with the TFileStream pointer. I mean: I am assigning a ContentStream, although I think that it doesn't make any difference when using directly the IOHandle->Write, right?

Comment: You do not need to assign `ContentStream` if you are calling `IOHandler->Write(TStream)` directly. But if the file is growing while your server is preparing/sending the response, you still have a race condition between the `Size` that you assign to `AResponseInfo->ContentLength` and the `Size` that `Write()` sees.  To avoid `Write()` sending more bytes than the `Content-Length` header tells the client, you can pass `AResponseInfo->ContentLength` as the `ASize` parameter of `Write()`. I'm going to add that fix to `TIdHTTPServer`, but I don't have an ETA of when it will be available.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing: setting a variable with the size before anything (for my own logging) and using that value for both the `ContentStream` and the `IOHandler->Write` parameter. Right now this is working fine, and I'm on rev 5204 (IIRC) so I'm in no hurry to update Indy

Comment: The current SVN rev is 5244

Comment: Yes, I saw this today while looking for info about this. I will try to update soon... I have some other libraries (RemObjects mainly) that depend on Indy and I don't really feel comfortable rebuilding it (even if it's quite easy compared to some other 3rd party libs) and hoping that nobody else breaks. Anyway, thanks for your help.